# How to take the margin top of parent div?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a parent div with sub div which are dynamically created by it's height and width. In my hand I have top left,margin top from parent div.But the problem is for first one it's working fine. When I place a second div, the margin top is getting calculated from the first sub div instead of parent div.
Here is my code:

```
$('#Droppable').append(
'<div id="PlaceHolder' + PlaceholderId + '" style="height:' + HeightInPx + 
'px;width:' + Widthinpx + 'px; background-color:black;color:white;text- 
align:center;color:yellow;margin-left:' + X + 'px;margin-top:' + Y + 'px;">' 
+ PlaceholderName + '</div>'
);
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show us your full code.

Answer (score 0):

To make the second `div` calculate position in relation to the parent `div` and not by its position in the children make its position absolute and the parent's relative

```
#Droppable{
  position : relative;
}
#Droppable > div {
  position : absolute;
}
```

And please, either remove the `id` from child element or make it unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Droppable').append(
'<div class ="child-divs"
id="PlaceHolder' + PlaceholderId + '"
style="height:' + HeightInPx + 'px;width:' + Widthinpx + 'px; 
background-color:black;color:white;
text- align:center;
color:yellow;
margin-left:' + X + 'px;
margin-top:' + Y + 'px;">' 
 + PlaceholderName + '</div>'
);

#Droppable{
   position : relative;
}


#Droppable > div.child-divs {
position : absolute;
top : 
bottom :
left :
right :
}
```

**Please fill** `top, bottom, left, right` **with values as per your requirement.**